# NestJS/ExpressJs too many parameters

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am trying to send a file to a NestJS controller but keep getting a `too many parameters` exception. I have installed `bodyParser` and updated the request size limit to get around a `request too large` exception.

main.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { ApplicationModule } from "./app/app.module";
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";

async function bootstrap() {
    const server = express();
    server.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));

    console.log(server);

    const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule, server);
    await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Controller:

```
import { Get, Controller, Query, Post, Request } from "@nestjs/common";
import { CloudVisionLogoService } from "./logos.component";

@Controller("logos")
export class LogoRecognitionController {
    public constructor(
        private readonly _logoRecognition: CloudVisionLogoService
    ) {
    }

    @Post()
    public async detectLogos(@Request() req) {
        console.log(req.files[0]);
        // return await this._logoRecognition.detectLogos(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Postman request (not shown, binary attachment of image):

```
POST /logos HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c95da069-c602-58a9-1e05-36456a527f02

undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is from [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) docs:

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules:
>
> busboy and connect-busboy
>
> multiparty and connect-multiparty
>
> formidable
>
> multer

I suggest you to use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) package because it's easy and many users use it

Comment: This helped a lot. Additionally, Postman automatically set my content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" which continued to break my code after I switched to multer.